# How do I use CGContext to draw on top of an existing UIView?

Tags: objective-c, uiview, core-graphics, cgcontext

I have a subclass of `UIView` in which I've added some subviews to in my `initWithFrame` method. I've added a background, amongst other things.

I want to draw some shapes on top of these views (which happen to cover the entire screen). But, when I implement `drawRect:` to draw these shapes, they didn't show up. Upon removing the other subviews, I realized that the shapes were begin drawn "under" the other subviews.

How can I draw them on top?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe, you should add transparent view on top of others and draw shapes on it?

Comment: Thanks for that -- I ended up creating another subclass of UIView, set its `backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]`, and then drawing with `drawRect:` in the new subclass. Thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 3):

Call `[super drawRect:rect]` at the beginning of the `drawRect:` for the owning view. This will draw all the subviews into the current context. Additional drawing you do for the owning view should then go on top.